# How can I pipe the output of an Akka Streams Merge to another Flow?

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I'm playing with Akka Streams, and have figured out most of the basics, but I'm not clear on how to take the results of a `Merge` and do further operations (map, filter, fold, etc) on it.

I'd like to modify the following code so that, instead of piping the merge to a sink, that I could instead manipulate the data further.

```
implicit val materializer = FlowMaterializer()

val items_a = Source(List(10,20,30,40,50))
val items_b = Source(List(60,70,80,90,100))
val sink = ForeachSink(println)

val materialized = FlowGraph { implicit builder =>
  import FlowGraphImplicits._
  val merge = Merge[Int]("m1")
  items_a ~> merge
  items_b ~> merge ~> sink
}.run()
```

I guess my primary problem is that I can't figure out how to make a flow component that doesn't have a source, and I can't figure out how to do a merge without using the special Merge object and the `~>` syntax.

EDIT: **This question and answer was for and worked with Akka Streams 0.11**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about the semantic of `Merge` where elements go downstream randomly then you could just try `concat` on `Source` instead like so:

```
items_a.concat(items_b).map(_ * 2).map(_.toString).foreach(println)
```

The difference here is that all items from `a` will flow downstream first before any elements of `b`.  If you really need the behavior of `Merge`, then you could consider something like the following (keep in mind that you will eventually need a sink, but you certainly can do additional transforms after the merging):

```
val items_a = Source(List(10,20,30,40,50))
val items_b = Source(List(60,70,80,90,100))

val sink = ForeachSink[Double](println)
val transform = Flow[Int].map(_ * 2).map(_.toDouble).to(sink)


val materialized = FlowGraph { implicit builder =>
  import FlowGraphImplicits._
  val merge = Merge[Int]("m1")
  items_a ~> merge
  items_b ~> merge ~> transform
}.run
```

In this example, you can see that I use the helper from the `Flow` companion to create a `Flow` without a specific input `Source`.  From there I can then attach that to the merge point to get my additional processing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Source.combine`:

```
val items_a :: items_b :: items_c = List(
         Source(List(10,20,30,40,50)), 
         Source(List(60,70,80,90,100), 
         Source(List(110,120,130,140,1500))

Source.combine(items_a, items_b, items_c : _*)(Merge(_))
         .map(_+1)
         .runForeach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you need to preserve the order of the input-sources (e.g. items_a must before items_b and items_b must before items_c) you can use Concat, instead of Merge.

```
val items_a :: items_b :: items_c = List(
     Source(List(10,20,30,40,50)), 
     Source(List(60,70,80,90,100), 
     Source(List(110,120,130,140,1500))
Source.combine(items_a, items_b, items_c : _*)(Concat(_))
```